# Array of numbers to batches of given sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I've a JavaScript array and sum as input

```
array = [4,8,2,4,2,2,8,12,4,2, 2]
sum = 12 // all the time sum will be 12
```

I want 2d array, the numbers in batches should be sum equals or less than 12

The output array should look like

```
[
  [4,8],
  [2,4,2,2,2],
  [8, 4],
  [12],
  [2]
]

4 + 8 = 12
2 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 12
...
2 is left at the end
```

Other examples

1) array = [6,5,3,3,3,2,2,2,2]
sum = 12

output: [ [6,3,3], [5,3,2,2], [2,2] ]

One the number is allotted to subset, it should not used to other subset

remaining numbers can be added to the last but sum should be less than 12, else add one more array and add remaining ones

> The input array can have any integer from 1 - 12

How can I get the output I want?

Comment: You can never achieve the sum of an array as 12 if `[7, 7, 7, 7, 7]`. here it can be `[ [7], [7], [7], [7] ]`. How do you want to deal with this? Or the max sum is 12?

Comment: @Soham,  If this is the case then the output will be [ [7],  [7],  [7],  [7],  [7] ]

Comment: what do you expect as the outcome for `[4,4,4,8]`?

Comment: If the input is [4,4,4,8] then the output can be [[4,4,4], [8]] or [[4,8],[4,4]] both are valid output

Comment: @MattEllen, The output will be maximum pairs forms sum 12, the remaining without has pairs will be appended at the bottom, but sum less than 12 in each sub array

Comment: But I mean which is chosen: `[[4,4,4],[8]]` or `[[4,8], [4,4]]` and why is it chosen that way?

Comment: @MattEllen in this case [[4,8], [4,4]] is valid, because this has max number of pairs. That is the expected output as well. I've mistakenly mentioned above ignore that

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand: you prefer pairs over all other types of grouping.

Comment: lets say if input input is [4,2,1,2,3,3,5,7,8,9] output can be [[9, 3], [8,4], [7,3,2], [5,2,1]]. maximum number of pairs with sum 12(duplicate numbers is not allowed, utilize the number form input).

Comment: Does the order of the pairs matter? Is `[[9,3],[8,4],[7,5],[3,2,2,1]]`  a valid output for an input of `[4,2,1,2,3,3,5,7,8,9]`?

Comment: No the order doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function. I commented the code as much as possible to clarify it.

```js
const example1 = [4, 8, 2, 4, 2, 2, 8, 12, 4, 2, 2];
const example2 = [6, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2];
const example3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
const example4 = [5,12,3,4,4,1,1,1,5,8,12,6,9,11,6];
const example5 = [4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9];

const lookAhead = function(array, searchFor) {
  return array.some(val => {
    return val <= searchFor;
  });
}

function findPairs(inputArray) {

  // First sort array in descending order
  inputArray.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  console.log("input", JSON.stringify(inputArray.slice(0)));

  // set variables
  const pairArray = [];
  const max = 12;

  inputArray.forEach(function(num, index) {
    // when looping the array we will replace values with null once completed,
    // Therefore if value is null no need to go futher
    if (num == null)
      return;

    // initiate pair value with current number
    const pair = [num];

    // set it to null in input array
    inputArray[index] = null;

    // if number equals to max (ie. 12) no need to go futher
    if (num == max) {
      pairArray.push(pair);
      return;
    }

    let total = num;

    // Loop through array again to see matching numbers
    for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {

      // Don't go futher if it is a null value
      if (inputArray[i] == null)
        continue;

      const add = total + inputArray[i];

      /* if the total is less than max (12) then we check if we have an edge case
       * For example in an array like [6, 5, 3, 3, 3], 6 + 5 is 11 but in next loops we  
       * will not find any "1" to get to 12. Therefore we escape this iteration and check
       * next numbers. In this case the result would be 6 + 3 + 3
       */
      if (add < max) {
        const found = lookAhead(inputArray.slice(i), max - add);
        if (found) {
          pair.push(inputArray[i]);
          total = add;
          inputArray[i] = null;
        }
      } else if (add == max) {
        // The addition is equals to max. Push the number and set it to null in input array
        pair.push(inputArray[i]);
        inputArray[i] = null;
        total = 0;
        break;
      }
    }

    // Push pair array from this iteration to  pairArray
    pairArray.push(pair);
  });

  console.log("output", JSON.stringify(pairArray));
  console.log("-------");
}

findPairs(example1);
findPairs(example2);
findPairs(example3);
findPairs(example4);
findPairs(example5);
```

Comment: thanks for helping me out here. You solution works great for all use cases. You are a javascript legent

Answer (score 0):

A little complex to understand but here you go...

```
let originalArray = [7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
let sum = 12;
let twoDiArray = [];

let CalculateSum = (array, element) => {
  array = [...array, element]
  return array.reduce((x, y) => {
    return x + y;
  })
}

twoDiArray.push([]);

originalArray.forEach(element => {
  for (let i = 0; i < twoDiArray.length; i++) {
    if (CalculateSum(twoDiArray[i], element) <= 12) {
      twoDiArray[i].push(element);
      break;
    } else {
      if (twoDiArray.length - 1 === i) {
        twoDiArray.push([element]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
})

console.log(twoDiArray)
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, it was working in given order, But when the input is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], the output is [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
  [ 5, 6 ],
  [ 7 ],
  [ 8 ],
  [ 9 ],
  [ 10 ],
  [ 11 ],
  [ 12 ] ]. The expectation is [
[1, 11],
[2, 10],
[3, 9],
[4, 8],
[5,7].
[12],
[6]
]. Is it possible to get this output @soham?

Comment: We need all possible batches of sum 12 pairs

Answer (score 0):

Here you... I will keep both answers open for future use of others...

```
let originalArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
let sum = 12;
let twoDiArray = [];

let CalculateSum = (array, element) => {
  array = [...array, element]
  return array.reduce((x, y) => {
    return x + y;
  })
}

twoDiArray.push([originalArray[0]]);
originalArray.splice(0, 1);

do {
  originalArray.forEach((element, index) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < twoDiArray.length; i++) {
      let summ = CalculateSum(twoDiArray[i], element);
      if (summ === 12) {
        twoDiArray[i].push(element);
        originalArray.splice(index, 1);
        break;
      } else {
        if (index === originalArray.length - 1) {
          if (CalculateSum(twoDiArray[twoDiArray.length - 1], originalArray[0]) <= 12) {

            twoDiArray[twoDiArray.length - 1].push(originalArray[0]);

            break;
          } else {
            twoDiArray.push([originalArray[0]]);
          }
          originalArray.splice(0, 1);
        }

      }
    }
  })
}
while (originalArray.length > 0);

console.log(twoDiArray)
```

Comment: The output of this algorithm is incorrect for an input of `[6,5,3,3,3,2,2,2,2]`. It outputs `[[6, 5],[5, 3, 3],[3, 3, 3, 3],[3, 2, 2, 2, 2],[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],[2]]` when it should output [[6,3,3], [5,3,2,2], [2,2]]

Comment: @soham, this above logic gives duplicate values in the subset , can you please add a fix to the above code